# Combine two UIImageView in to one image stretching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

When i tried two combine two `UIImageview` then images are stretching here's code what i am using

```
CGSize size =CGSizeMake(MAX(self.imgCapture.size.width, self.imgGallary.size.width), MAX(self.imgCapture.size.height, self.imgGallary.size.height));

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[self.imgCaptured.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,size.width/2,self.imgCapture.size.height)];

[self.imgGallaryCD.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+(size.width/2),self.view.frame.origin.y,size.width/2,self.imgGallary.size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Here's **First screenshot** is there is two UIImageview's

[image]

**Second screenshot** is when i am combine this image into one but image is stretching i want that aspect ratio like screenshot 1

[image]

Comment: try to set `UIImageView` mode to `scale to fit`

Comment: @AnuradhS Already using Scale to fit i think my problem is when i concating two image that is not proper i think

Comment: Try with [self.imgCapture drawInRect:CGRect.... instead of self.imgCaptured.image and [self. imgGallary drawInRect:CGRect instead of self.imgGallaryCD.image drawInRect...

Comment: @firstinq not working i tried that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is not "stretching". It is squeezing. It's a matter of simple arithmetic. Looking at your image context size and your `drawInRect` commands, we see that your image context is the size of *one* image, so now you are drawing both images at *half* width. So they are squeezed horizontally. You need the image context to be the size of both images added together.

Comment: may i know how can i achieve image context size  to gether? i am doing this CGSizeMake(MAX(self.imgCapture.size.width, self.imgGallary.size.width), MAX(self.imgCapture.size.height, self.imgGallary.size.height));

Comment: `MAX` means the width of the bigger _one_. You want the width to be the width of _both together_. That is called _addition_. You know: `+`.